# 00:00:00 DateTime.ToString become 12:00:00

Tags: c#, datetime

[image]

I have a datetime '2013-8-5 0:00:00'.

When I parse it to string using `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`, it returns "2013-08-05 12:00:00"

Did I write it wrong?

```
new SqlParameter("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
{ 
    Value = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") 
}
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: What is 0:00:00 normally called?  in the AM-PM scale?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want 0:00:00 instead of 12:00:00, then specify `H:mm:ss` instead of `hh:mm:ss` in the format string. `H` represents the hour as a number between 0 and 23; `hh` represents the hour as a number between 01 and 12.

**UPDATE:** Based on the code you provided, you shouldn't need to format the date at all:

```
new SqlParameter("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
{ 
    Value = startDate 
}
```

Comment: In fact, don't turn it to a string. Send directly like in the UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

"hh:mm:ss" is giving you exactly what you asked it to give you:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx
>
> The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will give you date time excatly like this "2013-8-5 0:00:00"

```
new SqlParameter("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
{ 
    Value = startDate.ToString("yyyy-M-d H:mm:ss"") 
}
```